# How to get the RelatedListId (rlid) of a certain related list in a custom object?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, mobile, related-list, navigation

I have a Master-Detail-Relationship between two Custom Objects. In order to make our app "mobile-ready" I need to navigate with the "sforce.one" object in a VF-Page.

For this I need the RelatedListId of the list of Detail-Objects. If you access a related list in the Browser via "Go To List" you can see the rlid-parameter in the URL.

I need to reference this rlid-parameter in my JavaScript code to navigate to the related List in S1. This works nice if I "hardcode" the rlid in the javascript but since these Id's change in other orgs i need a dynamic binding.

So the question is how can I get this rlid and make it available for my javascript (for example via Controller methods).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function navigateToList() {
    if( (typeof sforce.one != 'undefined') && (sforce.one != null) ) {
         sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList('the_rlid','{!parentId}');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: A controller method would involve writing a custom controller or controller extension that passes the Id to the the controller (get), the controller runs a query using the Id it `gets` to find the related list and returns the the Id of that object (set) using a `setter` method.

Comment: Exactly. The Problem I have is the query for the RelatedListId. I don't know where to find this specific attribute of my Master Object. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem. The so called "RelatedListId" is the Id of the custom field of the Master-Detail relationship on the detail object.

We were able to query this Id with the [tooling-api](/questions/tagged/tooling-api) described by Andrew Fawcett.

http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/

After implementing the Tooling API Class and creating an according Remote Site Setting you can query the Custom Field Id you need with the methods described in the link.

Since the sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList() works with the 15-Digit Id but the query returns the 18-digit Id, be sure to cut off the redundant last Digits( .substring(0,15) for example).